# Circular-moving text as activity label

Tags: android

I have an activity which serves for article displaying and I'd like to set article's title as activity title label.

As an article's title can be long I'd like to set a moving effect for text, right to left, circular.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to create **custom title bar**

check this [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)

Comment: Ok I just had to set marquee on!